# spark timestamp timezone in JDBC read/write

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark

I am creating a parquet file from reading data from oracle.

Oracle is running in UTC. I confirmed using,

```
SELECT DBTIMEZONE FROM DUAL;
```

Output:

```
DBTIMEZONE|
----------|
+00:00    |
```

Reading from JDBC and writing to S3 as parquet:

```
df = spark.read.format('jdbc').options(url=url,
                                           dbtable=query,
                                           user=user,
                                           password=password,
                                           fetchsize=2000).load()

df.write.parquet(s3_loc, mode="overwrite")
```

Now, I checked value of `spark.sql.session.timeZone`

```
print(spark.conf.get("spark.sql.session.timeZone"))
```

Output:

```
UTC
```

Now, I am reading data from S3 location:

```
df1 = spark.read.parquet(s3_loc)
df1.show()
```

Output:

```
+-------------------+
|             col1  |
+-------------------+
|2012-11-11 05:00:00|
|2013-11-25 05:00:00|
|2013-11-11 05:00:00|
|2014-12-25 05:00:00|
+-------------------+
```

`col1` is date in oracle and converted to timestamp in spark df.

**Why 5 hours are added in the output?** Database is running in UTC and `spark.sql.session.timeZone` is UTC.

### Note:

1. Both RDS and EMR are running in AWS US-EAST-1
2. On all the spark nodes, I ran `TZ=UTC`

Answer (score 6):

Timezone is reckognized by JDBC driver, which does not know about Spark's timezone setting, but relies on JVM's default timezone. Moreover, it ignores remote database session's timezone settings. You said you ran `TZ=UTC` - I'm not sure, but probably it didn't work. Check what `TimeZone.getDefault` tells you.

If, as I suspect, your JVM timezone is EDT (US-EAST-1 is Virginia), then `2012-11-11 00:00:00` read from Oracle by JDBC is interpreted to be in EDT. Displayed in Spark it's `2012-11-11 05:00:00` UTC and this is the result you got.

To fix it, override JVM default timezone when running spark-submit:

```
spark-submit \
--conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Duser.timezone=UTC" \
--conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Duser.timezone=UTC" \
...
```

Comment: You're save my life :-) Thank you! JDBC driver converts input Oracle's `Date` type to UTC on the fly. Now I found the graceful way to tell him "don't do it".