# Why doesn't Spark save timestamp based on the epoch in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, scala, apache-spark

Given a table in postgreSQL such as:

```sql
CREATE TABLE events (
    name                    VARCHAR(50),
    time                    TIMESTAMP -- No timezone, supposed UTC
)
```

I'm inserting events with Spark:

```scala
    val timestamp = new Timestamp(1000000000000L)

    val df = Seq(("test",timestamp)).toDF("name", "time")
    
    // Ensure Spark generated the right timestamp
    val timestampInDf = df.collect().head.getAs[Timestamp]("time")
    println(timestampInDf) // 2001-09-09 03:46:40.0   i.e. display for my timezone (Europe/Paris), GMT+2:00
    println(timestampInDf.getTime) // 1000000000000  

    df.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).jdbc(url, tableName, properties)
```

Then querying the timestamp in postgres:

```sql
SELECT name, time, EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM time) AS epoch FROM events
```

Which returns

```
name     |time                   |epoch     |
---------+-----------------------+----------+
test2    |2001-09-09 03:46:40.000|1000007200|
```

There is a 2 hours offset (corresponding to my timezone) with the timestamp I expected to save.

I'd expect the timestamp to be saved based on the epoch time. Instead it looks like Spark (or Postgres) took the display time, then supposed it was in UTC time (it was not), then saved the corresponding epoch time (hence with 7200 additional seconds).

What is the reason for this behavior?
What is a proper way to save a timestamp (without timezone information) with Spark?

Comment: Simmilar question is answered in the following post, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58264005/spark-timestamp-timezone-in-jdbc-read-write

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by PostgreSQL driver settings. Use `-Duser.timezone=UTC` to set your app timezone to UTC to avoid offsets.

More details on PostgreSQL date / time can be found at https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/java8-date-time.html